# Extended persistence context type with JPA 2 & Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I understand that an extended persistence context lasts the duration of the conversation or until the persistence context is closed by the container when the `@Remove` method of the stateful session bean completes (or the `stateful session bean` instance is otherwise destroyed).

Now obviously, the persistence context will also be closed in JPA 2/Hibernate when the bean is destroyed, but is there a corollary to `@Remove` in JPA 2/Hibernate?

Also, are there any pitfalls to keep in mind while using an extended persistence context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA/Hibernate are persistence technologies. They do not handle session (entity manager) management. They provide the entity manager and let other technologies manage it.

- manually - open and close entity managers
- EJB3 - as you mentioned
- CDI, spring, guice, etc. dependency injection frameworks.

[`PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType.html) should be handled by the framework which injects the `EntityManager` where `@PersistenceContext` is present. This can't be JPA/Hibernate alone.

Comment: 1. generally speaking - via proxies. 2. Yes, but better not. It again depends on the implementation whether it will fail, report a problem and continue, or silently continue.